# How do I stop TFrame from displaying a border?

Tags: delphi

I have created a class descending from TFrame. The class was designed visually in the Delphi IDE. 
When I add the TFrame to my main form, it looks correct in the designer. However, when my application runs, a thin black border is displayed around the TFrame. 
How do I turn this border off? I can't find any property of TFrame that relates to borders.

I am using Delphi 2010

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a simple app? Almost empty frame, almost empty form. Then show the content of both your .DFM files and both your .PAS files in your question.

Comment: Are you sure the problem does not lie in the frame container?

Comment: As Jeroen suggested, I created a simple app with empty form and frame. I could not reproduce the problem in the simple app. But when I use the *same* empty TFrame on my *original* project, the border appears. So i think Guillem is right; it is something to do with the frame container. Any idea what properties I should look at, or how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the border is being drawn by a 3rd party skinning component we are using. When I turn off the skinning, the TFrame is no longer drawn with a border.